# Python - Easy method for defining variables with values depending on version & types

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, variables

I want to write a function which should generate the base configuration. I have these variables for example:

```
var1 = "Value 1"
var2 = "Value 2"
var3 = "Value 3" 
var4 = "Value 4"
```

...

The value of the variable should depend on the version and types. Those two parameters are predfined.

Here is an example how to implement my idea with using if-conditions

```
If version == 1 && type == 2
var1 = "Value 1"
var2 = "Value 2"
var3 = "Value 3" 
var4 = "Value 4"

If version == 1 && type == 1
var1 = "Value 0"
var2 = "Value 0"
var3 = "Value 0" 
var4 = "Value 0"

If version == 2 && type == 2
var1 = "Value X"
var2 = "Value X"
var3 = "Value X" 
var4 = "Value X"
```

Do you know how to implement this without using if / switch-case? Is there an easier method? I tried to use decorators but I am not sure if it is the best way.

Thank you in advance!

I tried to implement this function with using if-conditions but I think there will be a better solution for my problem.

Comment: you could try using `dict`s, but i'm not sure it would really help your code readibility. 
The main advantage would be that you could easily store your dicts as JSON or YAML meta-configuration files, making it simpler to change the default behavior without having to edit any code.